# How to call an asp.net function from java

Tags: java, asp.net

Is there a way to call a function of an asp page from java (not javascript)??

Answer (score 1):

If you make the function invokable by visiting some URL (an ASPX page that invokes the function or w/e), you can then use URL in Java to invoke the function. However, if anyone decompiles your java code they'll see the URL which invokes the ASP function and they could invoke it themselves using anything (browser, in code, etc).